# C++ calculating size

Tags: c++

Consider a packet which consists of header followed by multiple values. If `hdr` points to the packet header and `lastValue` points to last value in the packet. can you please explain me the following code:

```
size_t  calcSize   = (lastValue - (char *)hdr);
```

What size does `calcSize` denote of the packet. In other words what are the start and end locations that is being considered for this size. Thanks,

Comment: What is the type of `lastValue`?

Answer (score 2):

`calcSize` will be the number of bytes in the packet.

Comment: For example if lastValue="the end"; let us assume the packet size until the starting byte of last Value is 32. Does size_t calcSize = (lastValue - (char *)hdr); give the result 32 + 7 = 39 bytes. I would like to know if it includes all the bytes of last value in calcuation of the above size.

Comment: The arithmetic will give you the right answer if `lastValue` is _one past the end_, that is, if it points to the terminating nul character of "the end". Otherwise you'll just get 32 in your example.

Comment: Yes, if you've got for the STL "one past the end approach". If not then you'll need to add 1 `size_t calcSize=1+(lastValue - (char*)hdr);`

Answer (score 2):

In this case this kind of arithmetic makes not much sense.
This is because your last entity/value in a packet may be for example 32bit(4byte) and substracting pointer to a header from it makes no sense - better is to use pointer to first byte after the packet in your substraction

```
int packetLen = (char*)firstByteAfterPacketPtr - (char*)headerPtr;  

      7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16   17  <-- example byte index
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
... |   header  |   v1  |v2 |    value3     |......
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      ^                       ^                ^
      headerPtr               lastValPtr       firstByteAfterPacketPtr
```

Your arithmetic would give:

```
 int packetLen = (char*)lastVarPtr - (char*)headerPtr; // 13-7=6 wrong
```

Correct is:

```
 int packetLen = (char*)firstByteAfterPacketPtr - (char*)headerPtr; // 17-7=10 ok
```

Be careful about pointer arithmetic - in case of (char*) you get byte difference, in case of pointers to 16bit eitities you get diff expressed in number of 16bit entities etc..

Answer (score 0):

This is pointer arithmetic: `(lastValue - hdr)` means the difference between two char pointers that means the size of chars between them.